# C# Return Reference

Tags: c#, reference, unity-game-engine, pass-by-reference

Similar questions have been asked, but I've been unable to find a decent answer to what I'm looking to do.

I have a function that unsets variables based on which variable is passed.

```
void DestroyEquippedItem (GameObject itemSlot)
{

            if (itemSlot == itemSlot1) {
                    Destroy (itemSlot1);
                    itemSlot1 = null;
                    itemScript1 = null;
                    return;
            }
            if (itemSlot == itemSlot2) {
                    Destroy (itemSlot1);
                    itemSlot2 = null;
                    itemScript2 = null;
                    return;
            }
}
```

I have 8 item slots and a few different functions that preform actions on these slots. Each of these functions look almost identical, with a list of 8 "if" statements going down to figure out which item slot we want to modify. I THOUGHT i had found a better way to do this by returning the reference to the item slot with another function, such as

```
GameObject GetSlotFromSlot (GameObject itemSlot)
    {
            if (itemSlot == itemSlot1) 
                    return itemSlot1;
            if (itemSlot == itemSlot2) 
                    return itemSlot2;
    }
```

which would then change my DestroyEquippedItem function to something like

```
void DestroyEquippedItem (GameObject itemSlot)
    {
            Destroy (GetSlotFromSlot (itemSlot));
            GetSlotFromSlot (itemSlot) = null;
            GetScriptFromSlot (itemSlot) = null;
    }
```

So my question basically boils down to "What am I doing wrong?"

I know I can't do a left-handed assignment like that, but being able to return a reference to the item to modify would make this REMARKABLY easier and shorten the code a lot.  Is there a way to do what I'm after?

Addendum: 
itemSlot1, itemSlot2, itemScript1, itemScript2, etc are all class-level variables in the inventory. These functions shown above are also in the inventory.

```
Public Class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject itemSlot1;
    GameObject itemSlot2;
    EquipItem itemScript1;
    EquipItem itemScript2;
    //etc...

    void DestroyEquippedItem(...)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what `Destroy` is doing but you can use local variables to store results of your Get methods and then assign them null:

```
void DestroyEquippedItem (GameObject itemSlot)
{
        var item = GetSlotFromSlot(itemSlot); 
        var script = GetScriptFromSlot(itemSlot); 
        Destroy (GetSlotFromSlot (itemSlot));
        item = null; 
        script = null;
}
```

Comment: Destroy is a unity method. It flags the gameobject for removal at the next frame, to put it simply.

Edit: Didn't mean to submit.  Wouldn't using local variables cause the local variables to be set to null?  I need the class-level variables to be set to null.

Comment: the local variables are assigned a reference which points to the same object as your class-level variables. So, they're the same thing with whatever you return from GetSlotFromSlot and GetScriptFromSlot

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could be solved with a simple loop. I'm assuming that you have some sort of array of itemslot? (Since you are checking them one by one).

```cs
foreach (int itemSlot in itemArray)
{
  Destroy (itemSlot);
  itemSlot = null;
  GetScriptFromSlot(itemslot) = null;
}
```

I'm also not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but there are better ways to do what you're doing than enumerating out all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates you are lost on several levels, so its tough to figure out where to begin.

First off, instead of having 8 variables for your GameObjects, try:

```
private GameObject[] itemSlots = new GameObject[8];
```

You also seem confused about how references work.  You can return a reference from a method and do whatever you want with it.  Just store the reference in a local variable first:

```
GameObject go = GetObjectFromSomeThing();
Destroy(go);
```

Just keep in mind that setting `go = null` won't do much for you here, because `go` is a new reference to an object you are referencing somewhere else.

However, what you seem to want to do is simply destroy and nullify one of the objects in your itemSlot list:

```
public DestroyEquippedItem(int index) {
    if (this.itemSlots[index] != null) {
        Destroy(this.itemSlots[index]);
        this.itemSlots[index] = null;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
// Destroy itemSlot 2
DestroyEquippedItem(2);
```